# How to add download pdf link in button in preview page using thymleaf html in java?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How to add a download link in HTML preview page using thymleaf java? I have added controller code for download and also html code which i tried. I need to refer download endpoint from the controller, So I have attached the code for download pdf. Download pdf has two scenarios as mentioned below(api/v1/download?s and api/v1/download?s=1). How do I interpret and refer this endpoint to create the download button based on user inpt(EX:api/v1/download?s=1), it needs to redirect to api/v1/download?s=1 and download the pdf via thymleaf html.

**Download URL:**

api/v1/download?s

api/v1/download?s=1

**// html code**

```
 </div>
     <a th:href="@{|/download|}">download</a>
        <span>Download</span>
    </a>
    </div>
```

**// download code**

```
 @GetMapping("/{id}/download")
    public void download(@PathVariable(BaseEntity.ID) String id, @RequestParam(name = "s") String sensitive,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
            Path file = Paths.get(profilePdfService.generatePdf(id, sensitive).getAbsolutePath());
            if (Files.exists(file)) {
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getFileName());
                Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what your actual question is. Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Edited my question, Still, you have doubt means comment. I will explain